# ‘for’ loop to add Sprites to collection using add method

Tags: java, android, for-loop, arraylist

I want to make it so that numerous sprites appear on the screen using an `ArrayList`. I'm getting and error for .add(R.drawable...

```
private Sprite sprite;
private ArrayList<Sprite> spritesArrayList;

spritesArrayList= new ArrayList<Sprite>();
        for (Sprite sprite : spritesArrayList) {
            spritesArrayList.add(R.drawable.spritesheet);}
```

Comment: You should probably post the error.

Comment: Please post the error. Also, I would rename your variable 'sprite' since there are two declarations of it.

Comment: because the spritesArrayList is generic for Sprite, and R.drawable.spritesheet is int. So you cannot add int into a Sprite List.

Comment: the method add(int, sprite) in the type ArrayList<Sprite> is not applicable for the arguments(int)

Comment: What your Sprite class is? Post the code of it

Comment: @CarlleRobinson you receive this error cause the actual argument that you're trying to add to Arraylist is Integer, but you need to pass whether Sprite object or the  object of class that extends Sprite class

Comment: Types of list states that it can contain that type or descendent of that specific type of objects. Ex - `List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
  list.add(new Object());
  list.add(new String());
  list.add(new Integer(1));`